# Axios POST to Docker container returns 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'

Tags: javascript, docker, axios

I've got an app running locally (port `8080`) a headless CMS running on a local docker container (port `8055`) and I'm trying to make an Axios POST request from my app to the docker container. This is what I'm trying:

```
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8055/auth/login',
    headers: {
      'email': 'admin@domain.com',
      'password': 'password'
    }
  }

  try {
    return axios.request(options)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8055/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

I've also tried adding this to the `headers` but I get the same error:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

How do I solve this problem?